# Merged a branch but there is no merge commit

Tags: git

I merged a branch in with git merge branchx, and it said:
Fast-forward

and there is no merge commit. How can I revert that merge if I want to?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your `git merge` was merely a fast-forward, there is no merge commit to be undone. You can undo the effects with

```
$ git reflog show master
$ git reset --keep master@{1}
```

In the future, if you'd like to force git to make a commit for fast-forward merges, use

```
$ git merge --no-ff XXX/master
```

Reference: http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2011/09/23/undo-a-fast-forward-git-merge/